# Facebook connect to external app inside iframed fan page content

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, iframe

I have an app that implements facebook connect to login/register.

I've also set up a fan page for that app. Suppose I render my connect button inside the iframe showing on the fan page. Will that work?

The objective is to allow people to register for my application while viewing the fan page for it.